# Вертикальный отступ у блока

Tags: html, css

Проблема такая. Блок с классом `.more` будто "застыл" в вертикальном пространстве. Я не могу его сместить выше, как мне нужно (что бы он был вертикально по середине основного блока). Подскажите, в чем загвоздка

```css
.event {
  min-height: 1px;
}
.date {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.date span {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #668333;
  font-family: 'ProximaNova-Bold';
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.date .number {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 1;
}
.date-desc h4 {
  color: #e67d6c;
  line-height: 1;
}
.date-desc .date-time {
  line-height: 1;
}
.date-time .day {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.more {
  margin-left: 90%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="events">
  <h3>upcoming events</h3>
  <div class="event">
    <div class="date">
      <span class="number">20</span>
      <span class="month">july</span>
    </div>
    <div class="date-desc">
      <h4>family sunday</h4>
      <div class="date-time">
        <span class="day">Sunday</span>
        <span class="time">9.30am</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more">
      <a href="">MORE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    <div class="date">
      <span class="number">20</span>
      <span class="month">july</span>
    </div>
    <div class="date-desc">
      <h4>family sunday</h4>
      <div class="date-time">
        <span class="day">Sunday</span>
        <span class="time">9.30am</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more">
      <a href="">MORE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    <div class="date">
      <span class="number">20</span>
      <span class="month">july</span>
    </div>
    <div class="date-desc">
      <h4>family sunday</h4>
      <div class="date-time">
        <span class="day">Sunday</span>
        <span class="time">9.30am</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more">
      <a href="">MORE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Задайте блоку `position: relative; top: -50px;` и смещайте на сколько нужно по вертикали изменяя значение `top`

```css
.event {
  min-height: 1px;
}
.date {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.date span {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #668333;
  font-family: 'ProximaNova-Bold';
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.date .number {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 1;
}
.date-desc h4 {
  color: #e67d6c;
  line-height: 1;
}
.date-desc .date-time {
  line-height: 1;
}
.date-time .day {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.more {
  margin-left: 90%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="events">
  <h3>upcoming events</h3>
  <div class="event">
    <div class="date">
      <span class="number">20</span>
      <span class="month">july</span>
    </div>
    <div class="date-desc">
      <h4>family sunday</h4>
      <div class="date-time">
        <span class="day">Sunday</span>
        <span class="time">9.30am</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more">
      <a href="">MORE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    <div class="date">
      <span class="number">20</span>
      <span class="month">july</span>
    </div>
    <div class="date-desc">
      <h4>family sunday</h4>
      <div class="date-time">
        <span class="day">Sunday</span>
        <span class="time">9.30am</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more">
      <a href="">MORE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    <div class="date">
      <span class="number">20</span>
      <span class="month">july</span>
    </div>
    <div class="date-desc">
      <h4>family sunday</h4>
      <div class="date-time">
        <span class="day">Sunday</span>
        <span class="time">9.30am</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more">
      <a href="">MORE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.event {
  display: table;
 width: 100%;
 clear:both;
}
.date {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.date span {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #668333;
  font-family: 'ProximaNova-Bold';
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.date .number {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 1;
}
.date-desc h4 {
  color: #e67d6c;
  line-height: 1;
}
.date-desc{
 float:left;
}
.date-desc .date-time {
  line-height: 1;
}
.date-time .day {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.more {
  margin-left: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="events">
  <h3>upcoming events</h3>
  <div class="event">
    <div class="date">
      <span class="number">20</span>
      <span class="month">july</span>
    </div>
    <div class="date-desc">
      <h4>family sunday</h4>
      <div class="date-time">
        <span class="day">Sunday</span>
        <span class="time">9.30am</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more">
      <a href="">MORE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    <div class="date">
      <span class="number">20</span>
      <span class="month">july</span> 
    </div>
    <div class="date-desc">
      <h4>family sunday</h4>
      <div class="date-time">
        <span class="day">Sunday</span>
        <span class="time">9.30am</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more">
      <a href="">MORE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    <div class="date">
      <span class="number">20</span>
      <span class="month">july</span>
    </div>
    <div class="date-desc">
      <h4>family sunday</h4>
      <div class="date-time">
        <span class="day">Sunday</span>
        <span class="time">9.30am</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more">
      <a href="">MORE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Попробуй так, и выровняй как душе угодно. Правда с line-height ты что-то намудрил